# Do Smart Contract wallets using ERC4337 allow wallet export?

Tags: accounts, smart-contract-wallets, wallet-transfer, erc-4337

From what we see in the ERC4337 documentation, SCW allow different architecture for transaction approvals. Unline EOA where we use ECDSA for signing transaction, with ERC4337, wallet developers will allow different ways for signing which enables new methods also for wallet recovery like Finger print, Social recovery, etc. My question now is, since we don't need to have any private keys, how can we change from one wallet provider to another. For example I want to change my Account from Metamask and export it to a new wallet. What do I need to have in order to login to same account from different wallet provider? I can not find information about that transition.

Answer (score 1):

ERC4337 is a complete game changer. It won't work with the current version of Metamask(or any of the existing wallets that I know of).

In fact, based on [this article](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337), ERC4337 wallets don't interact with the mainnet directly. Instead, the "transactions"(AKA UserOperation) are sent to the userOperation mempool, not the usual blockchain mempool.

UserOperation gets picked up by bundlers from the special mempool, and some magic happens before it is relayed to your wallet contract on the main chain.

Your wallet contract then does the usual stuff(send a transaction, buy tokens, mint tokens, etc) on your behalf.

Each UserOperation is attached with a “signature” for verification purposes. But this signature is not generated using a private key like before. Each abstract account contract may accept different kinds of signatures as proof, it is defined by the user.

Edit:

The "Export wallet" option is likely to work with the smart wallet contract on mainnet though.

Comment: Yes, all you said makes perfect sense to me, however my question is whenever you try to export your signature from one wallet provider to another, how do you do it. With private signatures is clear but how is it working now?

Comment: There won't be an export wallet option before there is a standardization signature system.

Comment: There is no standard for wallet provider standards Thus you may or many not be able to export, there might or might not exist another wallet that is compatible. We do not know yet, but a safe assumption is that there is no way to do it.